# How to use order_by on booleanfield using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I want to order the result of my mongoengine call on two different fields.

1. Open. This has status True or False. I want this because I want to
   display the open questions first
2. Opendate. Because I want to newest questions to show on top.

Combined this should create a list where I can see on top the open questions (ordered by creation date) and than the already closed questions, also ordered by creationdate.

The code I started with is:

To call the API:

```
questions = Questions.questions_of_user
```

To handle the call:

```
@queryset_manager
def questions_of_user(doc_cls, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(questioner=current_user.id).order_by('-openDate')
```

My first suggestion was to just add 'status' to the order_by (maybe with or without + or - ) would do it. But so far no luck.

Than I tried to only order by the open field, because I thought I was just making an mistake combining the two. So I got this:

```
@queryset_manager
def questions_of_user(doc_cls, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(questioner=current_user.id).order_by('-open')
```

That however did not work as well. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[More than one key](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/v0.18.2/mongoengine/queryset/base.py#L1014) can be passed in the `order_by` method of the queryset.

```py
queryset.filter(questioner=current_user.id).order_by('-open', '-openDate')
```